# Setting up Node.js with express.js on my 'portfolio' site

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm completely new to node.js but i'm trying to implement it on my personal site so that I start learning it. I have the node server running but i'm trying to set up the routing using express.js . All my files are typical static files .html, .js, .cs, .png , etc. Currently, the route gives me my index page on the 'home' page which is goo. If I attempt to navigate to the index of another diectory, I just get the 404 error page. My file structure is like this:

Server.js
package.json
node_modules
 -- views (Folder)
    -index.html (File in views)
    --Projects (Folder in Views)
      -index.html (File in Projects)

my Server.js looks like

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var path = __dirname + '/views/';

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("/" + req.method);
    next();
});

router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
});

router.get("/Projects", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path + "Projects/index.html");
});

app.use("/", router);

/*app.use("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path + "404.html");
});*/

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Live at Port 3000");
});
```

I've looked for the past ~18 hours at various resources and i'm just missing something i'm sure. My current idea of the issue is the navigation links in the html, however I've attempted changing those with no progress.

Comment: You don't really need to set up routes just to access static files -- you should set a path to use as the static directory -- see top of  http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: Hi Jackarms, I initially used this method. By just  using `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` but don't i need to define an index.html page? I also tried doing that in the options by using `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'),['index.html']));` however when i try to load my site it loads initially but is obviouslly missing all the css/js and if I refresh the page it throws a "Error: requested URL could not be retrieved"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only public file (like html, css, ..) you can put everything on a `/public` folder and add this instead of a router.

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Doc: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Every file will be accessible:

`/public/my-folder/my-file.png` > `www.my-dmain.com/my-folder/my-file.png`

Comment: Hi Arthur. I've tried this solution as well. For some reason when i try to navigate to 'Projects' i get a "requested url could not be retrieved." On the apache server this was working just fine. In fact, if I hard refresh my webpage it also throws a requested url not retrieved error.

Comment: Specifically i've done this, and now my site just gives out the error "requested site..."

 `var express = require("express");
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
//var router = express.Router();
//var path = __dirname + '/views/';
app.set('port', 3000);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
});`

Comment: It turns out the actual problem I was seeing was that my webhosts site owner interface had me turn on a daemon and proxy. When I was reloading my page to see the changes, the cache was not clearing. I changed the proxy on my server.js AND on my actualy webhosts's website and it's working now. Thanks